# Converting generic.List<Anonmoustype> to genreic.list<string>?

Tags: c#, generics

I am getting the frequent error when I write the below query indicating:

> cannot implicity convert type Converting `generic.List<Anonmoustype>` to `genreic.list<string>`?

I am unable to sort out what it does it mean?

I am getting the error when assigning Total = Ma in the below code

Here is the code:

```
using (var context = new SAIntegrationEntities())
{                
    var Ma = context.PAFs
        .Where(b => b.PostCode == txtaddrss.Text)
        .Select(b => new { b.GhouseNo, b.Eroad, b.City }).ToList();

    List<string> Total = Ma;

    foreach (string name in Total)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to display all the elements of querystring in a listbox of foreach loop

Comment: What querystring are you talking about? How do you want to display the items? You code does not contain logic to format and display your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to convert a list of one type to a list of a completely different type:

```
List<string> Total = Ma;
```

`Ma` has already been defined as a list of an anonymous type:

```
{ b.GhouseNo, b.Eroad, b.City }
```

How do you expect a type with three fields to be implicitly converted to a string?  And even if it could, that doesn't mean that a `List` of that type can be implicitly converted to a `List<string>`.

What do you want your list of strings to actually contain?  One of the properties?  Like this?:

```
List<string> Total = Ma.Select(m => m.GhouseNo).ToList();
```

All of the properties, joined by some delimiter?  Like this?:

```
List<string> Total = Me.Select(m => string.Join(", ", m.GhouseNo, m.Eroad, m.City));
```

You have to define some kind of conversion from the type containing three fields to the string that you want.  The compiler has no way to guessing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ma is an anonymous class with three properties: GhouseNo, Eroad and City. It's logical that this class is not a string.

Maybe you can try something like that:

```
var Ma = context.PAFs
                .Where(b => b.PostCode == txtaddrss.Text)
                .Select(b => new { b.GhouseNo, b.Eroad, b.City }).ToList();

foreach (string name in Ma)
{
  listBox1.Items.Add(name.GhouseNo + ", " + name.Eroad + ", " + name.City);
}
```